# How can I check to see if x is within y of z?

Tags: objective-c

In my case, I'm asking for a way to see if a value A is within 5 data values of value B. Is there an easy way to do this without the use of several if/else relational statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract A from B and then do a statement that would look something like this.

```
int c = b - a;

if(c < 5 && c > -5)
{
    //You know that it's within 5, so do that
}
else
{
    //Its not within 5, do this stuff.
}
```

I'm not sure if it would be the same code for objective-c but should be similar.

Comment: I'm exhausted so please let me know if I'm crazy.